# Why is Wireless 802.11g Faster Than 802.11b?

Tags: wireless

As far as I know, 802.11b and 802.11g operate on same frequency 2.4 GHz. But why does 802.11g achieve faster connection than 802.11b?

What's the mechanism of how 802.11g can achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

802.11g has a higher bitrate (54mbs, realisitc 22-26mbs).  802.11g uses the same radio-frequency bandwidth as 802.11b, but 802.11g implements  QAM / modulation.  So a 64-QAM modulation increases the bitrate to 54mbs theoretical speed. It's basically the accuracy of the wlan. How accuratly you can transmit/modulate your signal and how accuratly the client can receive and process the signal.

Comment: I tried to clarify what you're saying; however, the part about accuracy of the wlan is still a bit unclear.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Accuracy is how effectivly sender and receiver can send and receive QAM. You can send a highly modulated signal, but if you cannot receive it, it is no good. So when referring to accuracy I'm reffering to the amount of QAM, "how much I can get in one slot". More QAM = More potential bw: QAM (quadrature amplitude modulation) is a method of combining two amplitude-modulated (AM) signals into a single channel, thereby doubling the effective bandwidth.-> http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/QAM